# Fermentation not over?Cold crash or not?

Tags: fermentation, cold-crash

I am fermenting an ESB at 20C for 8 days. Target FG was 1.017 according to my recipe.
FG on 6th day was 1.013 ,7th and 8th day is 1.012 .I am not conserned about this difference as that i still have bubbles in my airlock.Should i leave it a few more days or cold crash now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the fermentation is complete, as the specific gravity has essentially stabilized. However, I'd leave it at 20C for another week at least to let the yeast clean up before cold-crashing. This is called the "[conditioning phase](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter8-2-3.html)", and can greatly improved the beer's flavour.